# Securely zero out memory in NSString

Tags: objective-c, security, cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management

On iOS, I was wondering, say if I read user provided password value as such:

```
NSString* strPwd = UITextField.text;

//Check 'strPwd'
...

//How to clear out 'strPwd' from RAM?
```

I just don't like leaving sensitive data "dangling" in the RAM. Any idea how to zero it out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you really can't. There are bugs filed with Apple over this exact issue. Additionally there are problems with `UITextField` and `NSString` at a minimum.

To reiterate the comment in a now deleted answer by @Leo Natan:

> Releasing the enclosing NSString object does not guarantee the string
>   bytes are zeroes in memory. Also, if a device is jailbroken, all the
>   sandboxing Apple promises will be of no use. However, in this case,
>   there is little one can do, as it is possible to swap the entire
>   runtime in the middle of the application running, this getting the
>   password from the memory.

Please file another bug with apple requesting this, the more the better.

[Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreporter.apple.com)

Comment: Link is invalid now, DO you have any other valid link or detailed article?

Answer (score -1):

While `NSString` doesn't have this capability (for reasons of encapsulation mentioned elsewhere), it shouldn't be *too* hard to have your app use regular old C-strings, which are just pointers to memory.  Once you have that pointer, it's fairly easy to clear things out when you're done.

This won't help with user-entered text-fields (which use `NSString`-s and we can't change them), but you can certainly keep all of *your app's* sensitive data in pointer-based memory.

I haven't experimented with it (I don't have a current jailbroken device), but it also might be interesting to experiment with `NSMutableString` -- something like:

```
// Code typed in browser; may need adjusting
// keep "password" in an NSMutableString
NSInteger passLength = password.length;
NSString *dummy = @"-";
while (dummy.length < passLength)
{
    dummy = [dummy stringByAppendingString: @"-"];
}

NSRange fullPass = NSMakeRange(0, passLength);
[password replaceOccurancesOfString: password
                         withString: dummy
                            options: 0
                              range: fullPass];
```

NOTE: I have no idea if this does what you want; it's just something I thought of while typing my earlier answer.  Even if it does work *now*, I guess it depends on the implementation, which is fragile (meaning: subject to breaking in the future), so shouldn't be used.

Still, might be an interesting exercise! :)

Comment: This requires that nobody else alias `password`, which is impossible to guarantee, especially given that the ObjC runtime can let you intercept pretty much everything