# "Zero out" sensitive String data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, security, encryption

A user enters their password into a textField. I set an instance variable to this value:

```
let password = passwordTextField.text!
```

I want to ensure this data is not preserved anywhere, and so I want to "zero out" this data.

Is this as simple as setting it to nil when I am done? Or setting it to an empty string and then nil?

Comment: Compare https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44121: *"It’s basically impossible to meet this requirement."*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296416/3141234

Answer (score 2):

These are general UI security tips (From ios 7 programming cookbook written by Vandad Nahavandipoor)

• Ensure that all passwords and secure fields are entered, by the user, into instances
        of `UITextField` with their `secureTextEntry` properties set to YES.

• If the user is on a screen that contains personal information, such as the user’s credit
        card number or home address, set the hidden property of your app’s main window
        to YES in the `applicationWillResignActive`: method of your app delegate, and
        set the same property to NO (to show the window) in the `applicationDidBecomeActive`: app delegate method. This will ensure that the screenshot that iOS takes of
        your app’s UI when going to the background will not contain any of your window’s
        contents in it. This method is recommended by Apple.

• Ensure that you validate the user’s input in your text fields/views before sending
        them to a server.
• Using the mechanisms that you’ve learned in this chapter, secure the user’s entry if
        you are storing it in files on disk or in the `keychain`.

• On screens where you accept a password or a numerical code for authentication,
        once the view controller is no longer on the screen, clear those password/code fields
        because the user won’t need them anymore. If you are not relinquishing ownership
        of those view controllers, their contents will stay in the memory. This includes the
        secure text field entries on those view controllers. It’s best to dispose of memory
        that contains sensitive information as soon as you are done with that data.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily zero out the memory. If `password`'s buffer is not uniquely referenced, some other reference will be keeping the buffer intact

Comment: @Alexander So how can I handle the string variable so it is "zero out" / scrubbed? -thanks

Comment: @vikzilla I don't know, I'm looking into it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to ensure there will be no trace of the data left on the system. As other answers suggested you could `nil` the variable but there is no guarantee the value is not saved in memory somewhere on the system.

I have heard of people storing sensitive data in `char` arrays but even then there is no guarantee it can be purged from memory, however it may be harder to track down the pieces of data if you use this method. I would however recommend **not** using this method in your particular case, because you would probably have to write your own UI elements as Alexander pointed out.

Comment: "storing sensitive data in char arrays" This would require you to write your own UI elements that don't ever use ObjC/Swift (structs can be copied, objects can be aliased) for backing storage.

Comment: @Alexander Ya I agree storing data in character arrays probably doesn't make sense for this particular situation. I just thought it would help illustrate how difficult it can be to purge a system of all traces of data.