# How to remove the string from the memory for security reasons in iOS? Is it even needed or iOS handle it by own

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, securestring

eg. For security reasons I want to ensure that the text entered by the user for the password does not stay in memory after use

Comment: After you send the password to the server for validating you can remove the string from the textfield and variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48548849/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14296271/1187415

Comment: In the callback of your database save method, simply do `yourTextFiel.text = nil`

Comment: @AlejandroL.Rocha I believe that will not remove data from memory

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Swift makes no guarantees as to what happens to memory once it's released. If you want to ensure password data isn't readable in memory, you should zero it out yourself.

Nice discussion of this on Apple's Dev forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4879

Answer (score 0):

I think it's automatically removed from memory since Swift implements ARC concept, where there is no garbage collection in iOS. Even in Objective-C now autorelease command can't be invoked on method call programmatically, since ARC has handled it.

From Swift Documentation:

> **Memory Managed Objects**
>
> Core Foundation objects returned from annotated APIs are automatically memory managed in Swift—you do not need to invoke the CFRetain, CFRelease, or CFAutorelease functions yourself.

Comment: ARC releases the reference to the sensitive data (i.e. the pointer to the memory address where the data was kept). But it does NOT zero out that memory. The sensitive data is still there until something new is written to that memory address. Which means a malicious attacker could (in theory) walk all memory addresses available to the application and read the data. This is an important distinction. ARC simply says, "This memory block is now available for new stuff." It does NOT delete the old stuff in that memory block.